# response error or success in each foreach value

Tags: json, ajax, laravel

inside foreach loop I have div response error and success, my problem is when single loop error show in all other foreach elements.

## blade

```
 @foreach($conferences as $conference )
<div>
 <div class="alert alert-danger" style="display:none"></div><br>
 <div class="alert alert-success msg" style="display:none" ></div> 
</div>
```

### ajax response

```
success:function(data){

                if($.isEmptyObject(data.error)){
                        $(".msg").show();
                        $(".msg").html("Successfuly Rated!!");
                        $(".msg").fadeOut(5000);

                 }else{
                  jQuery('.alert-danger').show();
                  jQuery('.alert-danger').html('<p>'+data.error+'</p>');
                  jQuery('.alert-danger').fadeOut(10000);

                    }
```

for single loop value, I may have error or success, but error or succcess shows on all other loops value.
Any Help Please

Comment: You have to use `foreach key` for separate all instance

Answer (score 0):

You're selecting `$(".msg")` and `jQuery('.alert-danger')`, which will select all elements which have the class `msg` and `alert-danger` respectively.

An example of your loop on a list of 2 conferences will generate this HTML:

```
<div>
  <div class="alert alert-danger" style="display:none"></div><br>
  <div class="alert alert-success msg" style="display:none" ></div> 
</div>
<div>
  <div class="alert alert-danger" style="display:none"></div><br>
  <div class="alert alert-success msg" style="display:none" ></div> 
</div>
```

As you can see, there are 2 elements with the class `msg`, and two elements with the class `alert-danger`.

So, when you run the line `$(".msg").show();`, you will show both `msg`s.

If you want to only show one of them, you'll need to use a more specific selector.

Comment: I understood the problem, but I don't have any idea how to overcome this!

Comment: Use a more specific selector

Comment: ```<div class="alert alert-success" id="msgRoom_{{$room->id}}" style="display:none"></div>```  then  ` _success:function(data){ $("#msgRoom". '_' .data.rateable_id).show()_` show blank page

Comment: That's the correct solution. Just change your selector to `$("#msgRoom_" + data.rateable_id)`